# Can't update pods to the latest version

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

I'm using react-native and I am trying to update the pods by using

```
pod update
```

But it updates nothing. However, when I use

```
pod outdated
```

It shows this

```
    Updating spec repo `master`
    $ /usr/bin/git -C /Users/IG/.cocoapods/repos/master fetch origin --progress
    remote: Counting objects: 15, done.        
    remote: Compressing objects: 100% (14/14), done.        
    remote: Total 15 (delta 11), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0        
    From https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs
        1bb3a72da66..f6d4f6f0e14  master     -> origin/master
    $ /usr/bin/git -C /Users/IG/.cocoapods/repos/master rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
    master
    $ /usr/bin/git -C /Users/IG/.cocoapods/repos/master reset --hard origin/master
    HEAD is now at f6d4f6f0e14 [Add] ScanbotSDK 0.0.2
    Analyzing dependencies
    The color indicates what happens when you run `pod update`
    <green>      - Will be updated to the newest version
    <blue>   - Will be updated, but not to the newest version because of specified version in Podfile
    <red>        - Will not be updated because of specified version in Podfile

    The following pod updates are available:
    - Firebase 3.17.0 -> (unused) (latest version 4.13.0)
    - FirebaseAnalytics 3.9.0 -> 3.9.0 (latest version 4.2.0)
    - FirebaseCore 3.6.0 -> 3.6.0 (latest version 4.0.20)
    - FirebaseInstanceID 1.0.10 -> 1.0.10 (latest version 2.0.10)
    - FirebaseMessaging 1.2.3 -> 1.2.3 (latest version 2.2.0)
    The following pods are deprecated:
    - Google
```

But my podfile doesn't specify any version:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'MyApp' do
    pod 'Google/SignIn'
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
end
```

I have react-native 0.47.2
xcode 9.2
cocoapods 1.5.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Found the problem.
I removed 'Google/SignIn' from the podfile and all pods were updated.
Not sure how to replace that pod but I guess Google has another pod since they deprecated this one.

Answer (score 4):

`pod update` doesn't automatically update the `master-repo`

Can you try :

```
pod repo update

pod deintegrate

pod install
```

It should update everything as needed, and do a fresh and clean install.

Comment: I tried that and It still downloaded the same versions

Comment: Then it comes from your podspec. Can you write explicitly the last version number in your Podfile ? Or can you print your podspec?

Comment: I think I found the problem.I removed Google/SignIn from the podfile and last versions were automatically installed. I guess I will need to find an alternative solution to using Google/SignIn pod since it is deprecated.

Comment: Not sure why there's a need to do "pod deintegrate"? Wouldn't pod install replace all the pod files?

Answer (score 0):

Try Latest pod of **GoogleSignIn** :

```
pod GoogleSignIn
```

& for more reference open [Google Developer Portal](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start)