# Terminal refusing to "pod update"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, terminal, updates

I searched all over but the closest answer is here [Can't update pods to the latest version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49883418/cant-update-pods-to-the-latest-version). However it did not work for me because I have no deprecated pods. And i cant leave a comment to ask someone about my case so I opened a new question.

I have no "specified version" and am using IOS 13 as the deployment target. Any ideas on how to update those pods? Thanks!

```
# platform :ios, '13.0'
target 'ChatApp' do
use_frameworks!

pod 'MessageKit'
pod 'JGProgressHUD'
pod 'RealmSwift'
pod 'SDWebImage'
# firebase pods
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'FirebaseUI'
  pod 'Firebase/Database'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage'
  
# FaceBook Sign in pods
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'

#Google Sign in pods 
pod 'GoogleSignIn'
  
end
```

[image]

Comment: What command did you run? What's the output of "pod update --verbose"? Could it be that you have a pod that's limiting the other one? Like imagine having PodB, compatible only with PodA in version 2.0.5?$

Comment: I ran pod outdated to see which pods needs updating. The moment I do, this screen comes.

Comment: Did You run pod update --verbose  ? What is the oputput/

Comment: I did run it, didn't find anything up normal, just a long list of file names.

Comment: I just noticed that all the "outdated" one are not directly present In your pod file, they are dependencies of others, except the `FBSDKLoginKit` (but another one might need it ad that specific version, or one of its dependencies at that other version blocking it to that version).

Comment: well, i guess your right. what do you suggest to fix the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because there are dependencies that need a specific version.

For instance if we see your "outdated" pods, except for `FBSDKLoginKit`, they aren't listed directly in your pod file list.

Let's have a look at your `Podfile.lock`.

The listing is a such:

```
- PodA
  - PodB
```

Where `PodA` needs `PodB`, it's by "indentation".

You use `FirebaseFirestore`.
We can see that even last version of
[FirebaseFirestore](https://cocoapods.org/pods/FirebaseFirestore) needs `abseil` at `0.20200225` (not the last version of it).

You might say, "hey, I didn't write pod FirebaseFireStore", that's normal, you are needing it indirectly (with a little sort of your `Podfile.lock`):

```
- FirebaseUI (9.0.0):
  - FirebaseUI/Firestore (= 9.0.0)
  - ...
- FirebaseUI/Firestore (9.0.0):
  - Firebase/Firestore
- FirebaseFirestore (1.19.0):
  - abseil/algorithm (= 0.20200225.0)
  - ...
```

You use `FirebaseUI`, that needs `FirebaseUI/Firestore`, which needs `Firebase/Firestore` in version 1.19.0, that needs the `abseil` at that version.
See the nightmare?

It's a nightmare to check, but you can do it yourself if needed, and find what the pod that is blocking the version of a pod. I just show an example.

Now, you are building dependencies, so they need to find a common version where it all works, you can't have different version really. Else we couldn't know which one to use, the version 4.0.0 where all changed, or the version 1.0.0?

Maybe [cocoapods-graph](https://github.com/erickjung/cocoapods-graph) (not tested) or [cocoapods-dependency](https://github.com/segiddins/cocoapods-dependencies) might give you a better idea:

[image]

Comment: I just checked the podfile.lock, its a nightmare indeed. But the problem with that is there are warnings within xcode saying some codes(from the pods) may be deprecated and the only way to fix those is when i update the version of the pods so I cant leave it as it is. I do believe there is a solution to this problem.

Comment: No, unless you make Merge Request to update the code of the one blocking the whole in the corresponding GitHub, or wait for a fix. You can open issues, or make merge request.

Answer (score 0):

Run `pod repo update` to update Your local database.

Comment: just did, nothing changed.

Comment: did You run pod install?

Comment: just added the podfile, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Run `pod repo update` to update then also run `pod install` and check output